# MongoDB Many Indexes vs. Single Index on array of Sub-Documents?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-.net-driver

Wondering which would be the more efficient technique for indexing my document's various timestamps that I need to keep track of, keeping in mind my application is fairly heavy on writing, but heavy enough on reading that without the indexes, the queries are too slow.

Is it better to have a field for each timestamp, and index each field, or store the timestamps and their associated type in an array field, and index each field of that array?

First option, separate fields, and an index for each:

```
{
    "_id" : "...",
    "Field1.Timestamp" : '2011-01-01 01:00.000',
    "Field2.Timestamp" : '2011-01-01 01:00.000',
    "Field3.Timestamp" : '2011-01-01 01:00.000',
    "Field4.Timestamp" : '2011-01-01 01:00.000',
    "Field5.Timestamp" : '2011-01-01 01:00.000',
    "Field6.Timestamp" : '2011-01-01 01:00.000',
    "Field7.Timestamp" : '2011-01-01 01:00.000',
    "Field8.Timestamp" : '2011-01-01 01:00.000',
    "Field9.Timestamp" : '2011-01-01 01:00.000',
}

db.mycollection.ensureIndex({ "Field1.Timestamp" : 1 });
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({ "Field2.Timestamp" : 1 });
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({ "Field3.Timestamp" : 1 });
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({ "Field4.Timestamp" : 1 });
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({ "Field5.Timestamp" : 1 });
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({ "Field6.Timestamp" : 1 });
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({ "Field7.Timestamp" : 1 });
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({ "Field8.Timestamp" : 1 });
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({ "Field9.Timestamp" : 1 });
```

Then there's an array of the timestamps and their status, with only a single index

```
{
    "_id" : "...",
    "Timestamps" : [
        { "Type" : "Field1", "Timestamp" : '2011-01-01  01:00.000' },
        { "Type" : "Field2", "Timestamp" : '2011-01-01  01:00.000' },
        { "Type" : "Field3", "Timestamp" : '2011-01-01  01:00.000' },
        { "Type" : "Field4", "Timestamp" : '2011-01-01  01:00.000' },
        { "Type" : "Field5", "Timestamp" : '2011-01-01  01:00.000' },
        { "Type" : "Field6", "Timestamp" : '2011-01-01  01:00.000' },
        { "Type" : "Field7", "Timestamp" : '2011-01-01  01:00.000' },
        { "Type" : "Field8", "Timestamp" : '2011-01-01  01:00.000' },
        { "Type" : "Field9", "Timestamp" : '2011-01-01  01:00.000' },
    ]
}

db.mycollection.ensureIndex({ "Timestamps.Type" : 1, "Timestamps.Timestamp" : 1 });
```

Am I way off the mark here? or which would be the better way

Comment: What do your queries look like?

Comment: The query uses the timestamp field in a $LT comparison: { "Field1Timetamp" : { $LT : "2011-01-01 01:00.000" }, "BatchExpires" : { $LT : "2011-01-01 01:00.000" }, "Prioritized" : true }

The indexes would also include the other two fields, but for simplicity sake I left them out, since there aren't several of them (there will only ever be one BatchExpires and one Prioritized field)

Comment: My thought was, are 2 indexes on an array of subdocuments more efficient than 9 or 10 indexes on fields not in an array...

Comment: I think fewer indices is likely to be the better approach but I can't say for sure, probably worth benchmarking both ways if it's critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically boils down to if 10 index of size N are more efficient than one index of size N * 10. If you purely look at reads then the seperate indexes should always be faster. The associated b-tree walks will examine a smaller keyset etc.

There are a couple of points to consider though :

- Indexes on array fields basically index each array element seperately. As such the lookup overhead will at most be 1-2 additional steps during the b-tree walk which is a negligible performance hit. In other words, they'll be almost as fast.
- Having 10 indexes may mean each update/insert will require more than one index to be updated (depending on if your indexes share a field or if you update more than 1 timestamp at a time). This is a significant performance consideration.
- Using an array index makes it a bit easier to add additional timestamps (e.g. Timestamp10).
- There is a limit to the number of namespaces you can use per database (24k) and each index takes up one. If you make a seperate index per field this might become an issue.
- Most importantly, the array index is way more straightforward and will simplify your code and thus maintainability. Given the limited performance differences I'd say this is the strongest motivation to go for an array index here.

Comment: So you are suggesting that for UPDATE/INSERT, having one single index should be a lot faster than the 10 separate ones?  I wasn't sure if there was more overhead to updating the index if it was an array of objects being indexed... I shouldn't ever really have more than say 20 fields that would need indexing, but that seems like a lot of fields to index...

Comment: It's faster if the alternative would means more than 1 index has to be updated. Array indexes are not treated differently to any other index. Every value in the array is indexed seperately.